# How to pass taskscheduler correlation id to c# arguments program

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments, taskscheduler

I have a C# console application, which is triggered on Windows Task Scheduler periodically, but I need to get the "Correlation ID" of process started and pass to my app by argument, like the code below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length > 0)
            Console.WriteLine($"This is the Correlation ID start process: {args[0]}");
    }
}
```

**See here more details about the information that I need**
[image: ScreenShot]

I found the "Add argument" option in Task Scheduler Action Window, but I don't know what to put there to retrieve "Correlation ID" process.

**See here the "Add argument" option above mentioned**
[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: I assume by this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215238/how-can-i-find-the-instanceid-correlation-id-of-the-scheduled-task-that-started that if you can't know it from inside the .exe, you can't pass it either.

Comment: Thanks @LucasMetal, but I really need the Correlation ID for my context.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394816/how-to-get-parent-process-in-net-in-managed-way). From the currently executing process you can get the parent tasks PID (process identifier) and use that as a correlation identifier.
If you really need access to the parents command line arguments then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633628/can-i-get-command-line-arguments-of-other-processes-from-net-c) should help you there.

Comment: Thanks @Bigtoe, but I really need the Correlation ID for my context, not PID.